# Keyboard shortcut for "delete" object in print composition?

Tags: qgis, printing

Is it possible to have/add a shortcut from the keyboard to "delete" an object in print composition?

I use to add objects from models then I have to print and delete them to add obects from another model with the same composition structure. So I have to delete many object every time.

I use QGIS 2.6.1 on windows 7

Comment: Waht do you mean by an object? A legend or a map? or do you mean a certain layer or even a feature within a layer?

Comment: I mean a map or a legend or a text cell or a label or an image or a graduated scale.

Comment: del key does the trick for me

Comment: What version? In my version it does not work

Comment: 2.6 -> 2.8 Maybe you have locked the component?